# Find cumulative sums of each grouping in a row and then set the grouping equal to the maximum sum

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

If I have a pandas data frame of ones like this:

```
 NaN  1   1   1   1  NaN  1   1   1  NaN   1
 Nan NaN  1   1   1   1  NaN NaN  1  NaN   1
 NaN NaN  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1    1
```

How do I do a cumulative sum in each row such but then set each grouping with the maximum value of the cumulative sum such that I get a pandas data frame like this:

```
 NaN  4   4   4   4  NaN  3   3   3  NaN   1
 Nan NaN  4   4   4   4  NaN NaN  1  NaN   1
 NaN NaN  9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9    9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we do `stack` with `isnull`, the create the sub-group with `cumsum` and `count` the continue 1 with `transform` , last step we just need `unstack` convert the data back

```
s=df.isnull().stack()
s=s.groupby(level=0).cumsum()[~s]
s=s.groupby([s.index.get_level_values(0),s]).transform('count').unstack().reindex_like(df)
     1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11  
0  NaN  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  NaN  3.0  3.0  3.0  NaN  1.0
1  NaN  NaN  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0
2  NaN  NaN  9.0  9.0  9.0  9.0  9.0  9.0  9.0  9.0  9.0
```

Comment: There's a `1.0` at beginning of row `1`. Maybe replace `.reindex_like` with `.mul(df)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang that is due to Nan not NaN:-) also updated

Comment: @YOBEN_S awesome as always, you are the master with these types of problems

Answer (score 1):

Many more steps than @YOBEN_S but we can make use of `melt` and `groupby`

we use `cumcount` to create a condtional helper column to group with.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd


d = """ NaN  1   1   1   1  NaN  1   1   1  NaN   1
 NaN NaN  1   1   1   1  NaN NaN  1  NaN   1
 NaN NaN  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1    1"""


df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d), header=None, sep=r"\s+")

s = df.reset_index().melt(id_vars="index")

s.loc[s["value"].isnull(), "counter"] = s.groupby(
    [s["index"], s["value"].isnull()]
).cumcount()


s["counter"] = s.groupby(["index"])["counter"].ffill()

s["val"] = s.groupby(["index", "counter"])["value"].cumsum()

s["val"] = s.groupby(["counter", "index"])["val"].transform("max")
s.loc[s["value"].isnull(), "val"] = np.nan

df2 = (
    s.groupby(["index", "variable"])["val"]
    .first()
    .unstack()
    .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
    .rename_axis(None)
)
```

---

```
print(df2)
   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
0 NaN  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  NaN  3.0  3.0  3.0  NaN  1.0
1 NaN  NaN  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0
2 NaN  NaN  9.0  9.0  9.0  9.0  9.0  9.0  9.0  9.0  9.0
```